# Making an if statement with 2 int variables. Python 3.7 Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.7

I'm trying to make an if statement with 2 numbers from an entry box from Tkinter. When I compare the 2 numbers, I get an error stating that the 2 variables I'm comparing are functions. Is it possible to make these functions into variables? I've tried var = int(var), IntVar, and var = float(var) and all are not working.

**Code**

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Who Is More Fat?")
root.geometry("800x600")

# LABELS
font1, font2, font3 = "arial 30 bold", "arial 18 bold", "arial 18"
Label(root, text="Welcome to the Who's More Fat Program", font=font1,
      fg="steelblue").place(x=0, y=0)

Label(root, text="Enter first persons name: ", font=font2,
      fg="black").place(x=10, y=200)

Label(root, text="Enter first persons weight: ", font=font2,
      fg="black").place(x=10, y=240)

Label(root, text="Enter second persons name: ", font=font2,
      fg="black").place(x=10, y=300)

Label(root, text="Enter second persons weight: ", font=font2,
      fg="black").place(x=10, y=340)

# TEXT BOXES
entry_box1 = Entry(root, width=25, font=font3, bg="white")
entry_box1.place(x=400, y=200)

entry_box2 = Entry(root, width=25, font=font3, bg="white")
entry_box2.place(x=400, y=240)

entry_box3 = Entry(root, width=25, font=font3, bg="white")
entry_box3.place(x=400, y=300)

entry_box4 = Entry(root, width=25, font=font3, bg="white")
entry_box4.place(x=400, y=340)

entry_box2 = float(entry_box2)
entry_box4 = float(entry_box4)

def calc():
     if float(entry_box2.get()) > float(entry_box4.get()):
        answer.delete(0, END)
        answer.insert(0, entry_box1.get() + " is the Fattest")
    else:
        answer.delete(0, END)
        answer.insert(0, entry_box3.get() + " is the Fattest")

# CALCULATE BUTTON

Button(root, text="Calculate the Fattest!", font=font2, bg="white", command=calc).place(x=5, y=390)

Label(root, text="Answer:", font=font2).place(x=290, y=400)
answer = Entry(root, font=font3, width=25, bg="white")
answer.place(x=400, y=400)
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Liam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in 
__call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:/Users/Liam/PycharmProjects/untitled/window.py", line 39, in calc
if entry_box2.get > entry_box4.get:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'function'
```

Comment: In your code, you wrote `entry_box2.get()` whereas the traceback says `entry_box2.get`.

Comment: Exactly ^ You just copied the traceback from your previous question

Comment: No I didn't. https://gyazo.com/a0ddcfa81327d4f1e18df09af5e9b7a2

Comment: @LiamWelsh, looks like you're running `window.py`, but editing `fat.py`. Or you forgot to save the file. The error message doesn't match your code, that's not possible

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot. However, the Tkinter window won't even open now. It just says the process finished.

Comment: Some terminology notes: it doesn't make sense to say "turn a function into a variable", python is a dynamically typed language with first class functions, so a function is an object like any other, an `int`, a `str` a `list` etc Variables in Python aren't typed, they can refer to any type of object. There are no *int variables*, there are `int` objects and variables which happen to be referring to an `int` object, which doesn't stop you from assigning any other type of object to that variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the mainloop, and I have removed

```
entry_box2 = float(entry_box2)
entry_box4 = float(entry_box4)
```

and it works:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.title("Who Is More Fat?")
root.geometry("800x600")

# LABELS
font1, font2, font3 = "arial 30 bold", "arial 18 bold", "arial 18"
Label(root, text="Welcome to the Who's More Fat Program", font=font1,
  fg="steelblue").place(x=0, y=0)

Label(root, text="Enter first persons name: ", font=font2,
  fg="black").place(x=10, y=200)

Label(root, text="Enter first persons weight: ", font=font2,
  fg="black").place(x=10, y=240)

Label(root, text="Enter second persons name: ", font=font2,
  fg="black").place(x=10, y=300)

Label(root, text="Enter second persons weight: ", font=font2,
  fg="black").place(x=10, y=340)

# TEXT BOXES
entry_box1 = Entry(root, width=25, font=font3, bg="white")
entry_box1.place(x=400, y=200)

entry_box2 = Entry(root, width=25, font=font3, bg="white")
entry_box2.place(x=400, y=240)

entry_box3 = Entry(root, width=25, font=font3, bg="white")
entry_box3.place(x=400, y=300)

entry_box4 = Entry(root, width=25, font=font3, bg="white")
entry_box4.place(x=400, y=340)


def calc():
    if float(entry_box2.get()) > float(entry_box4.get()):
        answer.delete(0, END)
        answer.insert(0, entry_box1.get() + " is the Fattest")
    else:
        answer.delete(0, END)
        answer.insert(0, entry_box3.get() + " is the Fattest")

# CALCULATE BUTTON

Button(root, text="Calculate the Fattest!", font=font2, bg="white", 
command=calc).place(x=5, y=390)

Label(root, text="Answer:", font=font2).place(x=290, y=400)
answer = Entry(root, font=font3, width=25, bg="white")
answer.place(x=400, y=400) 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm very new to python and programming in general and went a little outside my boundry trying to make this into a GUI. However, once I start something I'm determined to finish it. Could you explain exactly what you did with a little more detail so I can understand? Edit: I see what you mean by the main loop, I did have that in my code but didn't copy it completely sorry.

Comment: `mainloop ()` is necessary for the window to be waiting, and `entry_box2 = float(entry_box2)` and `entry_box4 = float(entry_box4)` it's no use

Comment: @LiamWelsh, it's not possible to convert an `Entry` object referred to by `entry_box`es to a floating-point number: `entry_box2 = float(entry_box2) TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Entry'`